# Table sorting issue on hidden row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rsqb7wp/7/)**

Table sorting issue on hidden row. I have created fiddle. Please help with this.

```js
function sortTable(f, n) {
    var rows = $('.videolisttble tbody  tr').get();
    rows.sort(function (a, b) {
        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);
        if (A < B) {
            return -1 * f;
        }
        if (A > B) {
            return 1 * f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm) {
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if ($.isNumeric(v)) {
            v = parseInt(v, 10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
        $('.videolisttble').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}

var f_sl = 1;
var f_nm = 1;

$(".matchhead").click(function () {
    f_sl *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_sl, n);
});

$(".timehead").click(function () {
    f_nm *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_nm, n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2> Before sorting</h2>
  
<table class="table table-responsive videolisttble dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0">
  <thead>
   <tr><th class="matchhead">Match</th><th class="timehead">Date &amp; Time</th><th> Action</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
   
   <tr class="manageiconswrap" role="row">
    <td>D Team  vs Team E</td>
    <td>Tuesday March 15th, 2016, 05:00 PM</td>
    <td class="actioncont">          
    </td>
   </tr>     
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">D Team</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">Team E</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="manageiconswrap">
    <td>C Team  vs Team F</td>
    <td>Sunday October 18th, 2015, 03:00 PM</td>
    <td class="actioncont"></td>
   </tr> 

   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">C Team</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">Team F</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="manageiconswrap">
    <td>A Team  vs Team B</td>
    <td>Sunday October 18th, 2015, 03:00 PM</td>
    <td class="actioncont"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">A Team</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">Team B</td>
   </tr>
   
 </tbody>
</table>
  
  
   
<h2> After sorting</h2>


<table class="table table-responsive  dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0">
  <thead>
   <tr><th class="">Match</th><th class="">Date &amp; Time</th><th> Action</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
   
   
   <tr class="manageiconswrap">
    <td>A Team  vs Team B</td>
    <td>Sunday October 18th, 2015, 03:00 PM</td>
    <td class="actioncont"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">A Team</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">Team B</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="manageiconswrap">
    <td>C Team  vs Team F</td>
    <td>Sunday October 18th, 2015, 03:00 PM</td>
    <td class="actioncont"></td>
   </tr> 

   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">C Team</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">Team F</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="manageiconswrap" role="row">
    <td>D Team  vs Team E</td>
    <td>Tuesday March 15th, 2016, 05:00 PM</td>
    <td class="actioncont">          
    </td>
   </tr>     
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">D Team</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="donotsort">
    <td colspan="3" style="display:none;"class="toggledropcont">Team E</td>
   </tr>
   
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Describe you problem please..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki please click on the table head in fiddle. you will undestand my problem

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rsqb7wp/8/)**

Because of nested tables the function will be confused between tables rows and sort also the child table rows,to avoid that you have to change your selector to target just `.videolisttble` direct rows.

Use `>` sign to target direct child :

```
var rows = $('.videolisttble>tbody>tr').get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but each hidden row should append next to manageiconswrap class

Comment: Ok please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.